# Ruby shoes, communicating between stacks

Tags: ruby, variables, shoes

I'm having a big issue here. I can't communicate between shoes stacks.
Here is a resumed exemple, in order to show the problem:

```
Shoes.app do 
  stack :width => "100%", :height => "25%" do
    button "" do
      a.show
    end
  end
  a = stack :width => "100%", :height => "25%", :hidden => true do
    b = para "lol"
  end
end
```

As you have understood, it can't work because the variable a is declared before being able to be used. However, I have a lot of things I have to append to the second stack thanks to a button on the first stack, it is not possible at all. I don't know if there's a way.
I have to keep the order of the stacks. I don't want the "a.show" be after the "a" stack.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use global variables (those prefixed with `$`). That's bad practice

Use instance variables prefixed with `@` and that will be visible across the Shoes flows.

You're working inside of an App object, and you should be using instance variables. 
Check out [the Shoes Rules](http://shoesrb.com/manual/Rules.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

okay, maybe I have resumed my problem too much.
I have found a solution I have to adapt it on my bigger code now.

Replacing a by $a did the trick.